# Settings app is not loading in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, system-settings

The Settings app is not loading in Ubuntu 20.04 after using it for 3 days. When I installed Ubuntu it was working fine, but now none of the categories in Settings like Network, Displays and Date & Time are working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to reinstall GNOME Settings:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```